# Algorithm in PHP to count and display variables

Tags: php, algorithm, variables, counting

I can't find a way to read variables in a URL or in a vector or in text form so that it returns just the value which is repeating. In the case that it is only one value, I need to display it, or in the case there are all  different values, I need to display all of them.

For example if I have 1,2,3,1,4, I would like it to display 1, and if I have 1,2,3,4 to display all of them.

```
$values = $_GET['intrebare'];
$count = count($values);

foreach($values as $val =>$array) 
{
    //echo $val . '<br/>';
    //var_dump($array);

    if(is_array($array))
    {
        var_dump($array);
    }
    else
    {
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use array_unique on your input array to see if there are no doubles. If an array after [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) is just as large as before, you should print all values.

From what I understand, if the array does not contain all unique values, you want to print all that occur multiple times. If you only want to print values that occur more than once you can first check with [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) what values occur more than once and print them.

The rest is up to you :)

Comment: hoppa I have a mistake in my question, I mean from URL instead in URL, sorry, and can you help me with a code? pleasecan you help me, it`s very very important please

Comment: Well, at the least you'll need to provide a sample URL.

Comment: What is in $_GET['intrebare']? And please format your code next time you edit. This site is about helping, but you need to facilitate the people helping you a bit more :)

Comment: i formated it,and $_GET['intrebare'] are the values from the selected checkboxes with same name

Comment: Come on, work with me here. I'd like to see an example of what is in intrebare. Just saying that they're the result of checkboxes isn't going to help much.

Comment: do you want the website(link) to see it does?

Comment: and what kinds of values do the checkboxes have?

Comment: I'd prefer a var_dump of get['interbare'] as well

Comment: numbers. but i want a code to display the values sent from another page(i want that values to be: when i have 1,2,3,1. i want to display 1 or when i have 1,2,3,4 to display all of them). and that values are from $_GET['intrebare'] which is the values of checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

Using `array_count_values` is the easiest way to go, but in case you need to grasp how to accomplish what you're looking for, here's the verbose version.

```
$input = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 1);
$unique = array_unique($input);

// If $input and $unique are different in length, 
// there is one or more repeating values
if (count($input) !== count($unique)) {
    $repeat = array();

    // Sort values in order to have equal values next to each other
    sort($input);

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($input) - 1; $i++) {
        // If two adjacent numbers are equal, that's a repeating number.
        // Add that to the pile of repeated input, disregarding (at this stage)
        // whether it is there already for simplicity.
        if ($input[$i] === $input[$i - 1]) {
            $repeat[] = $input[$i];
        }
    }

    // Finally filter out any duplicates from the repeated values
    $repeat = array_unique($repeat);

    echo implode(', ', $repeat);
} else {
    // All unique, display all
    echo implode(', ', $input);
}
```

The concise one-liner-ish version would be:

```
$input = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 1);
$repeat = array_keys(
    array_filter(
        array_count_values($input), 
        function ($freq) { return $freq > 1; }
    )
);

echo count($repeat) > 0 
        ? implode(', ', $repeat)
        : implode(', ', $input);
```